# Java applet Security Warning checkbox

Tags: java, security, applet

Loading an applet after installing JRE 7 update 55 I get a "Security Warning" dialog.

I check the checkbox for 
"Do not show this again for this app and web site" and click on "Allow". The applet loads.

![Security Warning window][[https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN2Cx.png]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN2Cx.png%5d)

However if i navigate away from the applet and load it again, the dialog comes up again. It is as if it does not remember the checkbox option.

The  Caller-Allowable-Codebase is set to * in the applets manifest file because the app needs to be deployed on any server designated by our client.

Is this a jre u55/u60 bug? or is there something that needs to be done to make that checkbox functional?

Additional information:
The applet runs with no problem (displaying the warning window just once), I have the problem with repetetive displaying just on one environment. The main difference is, that it runs on Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS 8.5

I have checked the lap file where the choice is saved (in `c:\Users\"user_name"\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\` search in subfolders for files containing "js.allowed.codebases=") and for other environment I have:

```
js.allowed.codebases=https//trial.domain.com\:443
```

but for that one problematic, for the first time allowing, it creates the same, and with every other allowing, it saves the same web in the parameter as follows:

```
js.allowed.codebases=https//trial.domain.com\:443/thttps//trial.domain.com\:443
```

next loop:

```
js.allowed.codebases=https//trial.domain.com\:443/thttps//trial.domain.com\:443/thttps//trial.domain.com\:443
```

When I put the domain name into the Caller-Allowable-Codebase manifest parameter, the security window does not show up.

And one more thing - when I load the page/applet on localhost (on that server), it works properly. It seems, that the problem could be also connected somehow with the access via domain?

...any idea?

Thanks

Comment: same problem also with latest JRE version (1.7.0_67-b01)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am running into this issue as well with 1.8.0_31.

Time to put on your tinfoil hats.  Maybe the problem has to do with a domain name having a "t" at the beginning of it.  I am running two applications:

- `http://this.sucks.com/appname/` does NOT remember the "Allow/Do Not Allow" decision
- `http://applets.suck.com/appname/` DOES remember the "Allow/Do Not Allow" decision

I am guessing somewhere along the line, Java is treating /t as an escaped character (for some reason).  If I access the "t" server using an IP address or localhost, the decision is remembered.

I also noticed that your domain name begins with a "t", which can't just be coincidence :)

Here is another domain name with a "t": https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8065891